# How to animate an element's color from one color to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I'm trying to make my own website, and I need to fade a paragraph in and out via a jQuery animation. For this, I've gotten jQuery UI, and I'm trying to animate a test element's color, but it doesn't seem to work. The div's initial color is a semi-transparent, light-grey color (rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.25) to be specific), and I'm trying to animate it to a fully-opaque black (#000000). I'm almost certain my syntax is correct, but I'm not sure I included everything in the right order in the document's header. Could I get some help here? Here's the code for the included scripts and stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainpagestyle.css">

<script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/mainscript.js"></script>
```

Here's the code for "mainscript.js," in case it's anything to do with the script syntax:

```
$(".click-leftmenu").mouseup(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("out") == 0) {
        $(this).animate({width: "4em", height: "4em"}, 100);
        $(this).prev().animate({height: "4em"}, 100);
        $(".click-leftmenu[out=1]").prev().animate({width: "0%", height: "0%"});
        $(".click-leftmenu").attr("out", 0);
        $(this).prev().animate({width: "50%"}, 500);
        $(this).prev().animate({height: "40em"});
        $(this).prev().animate({color: "#000000"});
        $(this).attr("out", 1);
    }
});
```

Full code can be found here:

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/Tv5ssW5j)

[jQuery](http://pastebin.com/CVf89Ukt)

Comment: I don't see any code that you wrote for this at all.

Comment: Edited, realized I wasn't thorough enough.

Comment: Cau include `html` at Question?

Comment: Have you tried toggling css classes to change color also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to animate the background color. I'm not sure what the other elements are used for and since we don't have any HTML I excluded the rest.

```
$(document).on("click", ".click-leftmenu", function() {
  $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#000000"
  }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated, I guess I shouldn't have expected all animations to be in 100% CSS, at least for UI.

Comment: +Unity_Paradox animations can be in 99% CSS. In fact, you don't even need to use JQuery. However, your question had JQuery specified...